# How to distinguish between Telephonenumber and Mobilephonenumber

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have the following problem:

I have a RawContactID and want to get every information about this contact. I run a query like this:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.RAW_CONTACT_ID +" = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{contacts[0].get(0)};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

After that I run the cursor through a lot of elseif-Statemens to distinguish betweene the different MIME-Types and read the informations. Works fine, besides that it is very much code only to read informations about one contact, but ok.

The problem is that the MIME-Type for Mobilephonenumber and Telephonenumber are the *same* (vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2)??

How can i distinguish between those to different informations?

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` will let you distinguish between the types.  There is a long list of which `TYPE_HOME` and `TYPE_MOBILE` are just two.

The sdk reference also states

`You can use all columns defined for ContactsContract.Data as well as the following aliases.`

Comment: Hell not, then I have to switch-case _all_ MIME-Typs AND _all_ Data-Typs *argh* That will be a lot of code ... But thanks anyway, perfect answer :)